# Isn't $\lceil \frac{xy}{z}\rceil =\lfloor \frac{xy+y-1}{z}\rfloor$ for any positive integers $x,y,z$?

Tags: integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I was pretty sure that:

$$\left\lceil\frac{xy}{z}\right\rceil = \left\lfloor\frac{xy+y-1}{z}\right\rfloor$$

for positive integers $x,y,z$.

But I'm getting wrong results testing it in Python 3:

```
from math import ceil

x = 40000000000000000
y = 400000000000000070
z = 80000000000000014

print(ceil(x*y/z))  # 200000000000000000
print((x*y+y-1)//z) # 200000000000000004
#
```

Does anyone here have a clue where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Don't know if your formula is correct. Assuming that it is correct, please take care of the possible numerical errors due to finite arithmetic...

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): " The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title." Particularly in this case, you should write the hypothesis of $x$, $y$ and $z$ being positive integers in the body of the question, not only in the title.

Comment: Also, "Does anyone here have a clue where I've gone wrong?" is not part of the code.

Answer (score 4):

The formula is obviously false: for $z=1$ and $y\ne 1$ we have $xy \ne xy+y-1$.

As you a observed in a comment, the correct formula is $$\left\lceil\frac{xy}{z}\right\rceil = \left\lfloor\frac{x y+z-1}{z}\right\rfloor$$

for positive integers $x$, $y$ and $z$.

It can be proved as follows:

Call $n = \left\lceil\frac{xy}{z}\right\rceil$, then

$$n-1<\frac{xy}{z}\le n$$
$$n z-z<x y\le n z$$

Since $nz-z$ and $xy$ are integers, we have
$$n z-z+1\le x y\le n z$$
$$nz \le xy+z-1 \le nz+z-1 < nz+z$$
$$n \le \frac{xy+z-1}{z} < n+1$$
so $$\left\lfloor\frac{x y+z-1}{z}\right\rfloor = n$$